# Server control link button postbacking in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In Web application, asp.net web application I am using one link button/Image button of asp.net server control, when I click on that control it is loging out from the site. What could be the reason can you help me please.

The code is like this :

```
   <img src="Images/aaa.png" width="24px" height="24px"/>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkhlpbtn" runat="server" PostBackUrl="../ss/ssn.aspx"  
   class="blue1_link"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Change This PostBackUrl="../ss/ssn.aspx" to PostBackUrl="~/ss/ssn.aspx"

Comment: k, i will try and inform you raghu

Comment: Also, why are you using `<asp:LinkButton>`? Why not a straightforward `<a href="#">`?

Comment: yeah sure, thank you i will also implement this anchor tag and i will intimate you.

Answer (score 0):

(Posting my suggestion as an answer for sweet, sweet karma):

Also, why are you using `<asp:LinkButton>`? Why not a straightforward `<a href="#">`?